# Calendar only showing one row JS

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, calendar

I'm not sure if I'm missing something I need to add to my HTML or what, but I need this done for class. I wrote my JavaScript in a way that made sense to me and yet I'm only getting the first row of the month. The days are numbered correctly as well. Everything seems to be okay, but I'm obviously missing something since I am not getting my desired result.

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready(function() {
  var getMonthText = function(currentMonth) {
    if (currentMonth === 0) {
      return "January";
    } else if (currentMonth === 1) {
      return "February";
    } else if (currentMonth === 2) {
      return "March";
    } else if (currentMonth === 3) {
      return "April";
    } else if (currentMonth === 4) {
      return "May";
    } else if (currentMonth === 5) {
      return "June";
    } else if (currentMonth === 6) {
      return "July";
    } else if (currentMonth === 7) {
      return "August";
    } else if (currentMonth === 8) {
      return "September";
    } else if (currentMonth === 9) {
      return "October";
    } else if (currentMonth === 10) {
      return "November";
    } else if (currentMonth === 11) {
      return "December";
    }
  };
  // get current month and year
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();

  // get name of current month
  var monthName = getMonthText(currentMonth);

  // calander display
  var displayName = monthName + ' ' + currentYear;

  // update header
  $('#month_year').text(displayName);

  var getLastDayofMonth = function(currentMonth) {
    // set last day variable and gets next month
    // sets the day of the next month to 0
    // since there is no day 0 it get the last day of the previous month
    var lastDay = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();
    return lastDay;
  };
  // get first day of month
  var firstDay = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay();

  // get last day of month
  var lastDay = getLastDayofMonth(currentMonth);

  // reference to table
  var $calendarTable = $('#calendar');

  // create rows and cells for calendar
  var dayCounter = 1;
  var $row = $('<tr>');

  for (var day = 0; day < 7; day++) {
    if (day < firstDay) {
      $row.append('<td></td>'); // Add blank cells before the first day
    } else if (dayCounter <= lastDay) {
      $row.append('<td>' + dayCounter + '</td>');
      dayCounter++;
    } else {
      $row.append('<td></td>'); // Add blank cells after the last day
    }

    if (day === 6 || dayCounter > lastDay) {
      $calendarTable.append($row); // Append the completed row

      if (dayCounter > lastDay) {
        break; // Exit the loop when all days are added
      }

      $row = $('<tr>'); // Create a new row for the next week
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="calendar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1><span id="month_year">&nbsp;</span></h1>

    <table id="calendar">
      <tr>
        <th>Sun</th>
        <th>Mon</th>
        <th>Tue</th>
        <th>Wed</th>
        <th>Thu</th>
        <th>Fri</th>
        <th>Sat</th>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rewrite. Please study it and ask questions if needed

Your main issue was that you only ran your code for 7 days instead of the whole month

```js
"use strict";
const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
const getLastDayofMonth = (currentYear,currentMonth) => new Date(currentYear, currentMonth + 1, 0).getDate();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var currentDate = new Date();
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
  var currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
  var monthName = months[currentMonth];
  var displayName = monthName + ' ' + currentYear;

  $('#month_year').text(displayName);

  var weekDayOfTheFirst = new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, 1).getDay();
  var lastDay = getLastDayofMonth(currentYear,currentMonth);

  var $calendarTable = $('#calendar');
  let $row = $('<tr>');

  // Add leading cells
  for (let i = 0; i < weekDayOfTheFirst; i++) {
    $row.append('<td></td>');
  }

  let currentWeekDay = weekDayOfTheFirst;

  // Add calendar days
  for (let day = 1; day <= lastDay; day++) {
    $row.append(`<td>${day}</td>`);
    currentWeekDay++;

    // If it's a Sunday or the last day of the month, append the row
    if (currentWeekDay % 7 === 0 || day === lastDay) {
      // Add trailing cells if it's the last day of the month
      if (day === lastDay) {
        const trailingCells = 7 - (currentWeekDay % 7);
        for (let i = 0; i < trailingCells; i++) {
          $row.append('<td></td>');
        }
      }

      $calendarTable.append($row);
      $row = $('<tr>');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
td {
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calendar</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="calendar.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="calendar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <h1><span id="month_year">&nbsp;</span></h1>

    <table id="calendar">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Sun</th>
          <th>Mon</th>
          <th>Tue</th>
          <th>Wed</th>
          <th>Thu</th>
          <th>Fri</th>
          <th>Sat</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```